# Make a NSTableCellView editable

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I created a **View-Based** `NSTableView` with a single column. This column is populated with a standard `NSTableCellView` from Interface Builder (I chose the version with image and textfield).

Now I want to make the **textfield** in the column **editable**.

My first attempt was to modify the `NSTextField` from Interface builder and set its behaviour as `Editable`. It works, indeed when I select a row and I push the `enter key` the field becomes editable and I can change its value. I thought I would be able to intercept  this change thanks to some `NSTableViewDataSource` method like  `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` but this method never gets called in response of a textfield edit action.

Which is the right way to deal with editable field in a view-based NSTableView system? I suppose that the `NSTableViewDataSource` has something to do with it but I don't know how to get its methods called.

Comment: You don't say *why* you want to intercept the edit?

Comment: Because I need to use the value to edit data in the datasource.

Answer (score 3):

Create a subclass of NSTableCellView. (The appropriate .h and .m files) Make the class respond to the NSTextFieldDelegate protocol. Implement the control:textShouldEndEditing: method. Make this subclass the delegate of your label control.

Here is some example code.

CategoryListCell.h

```
@interface CategoryListCell : NSTableCellView
@end
```

CategoryListCell.m

```
@interface CategoryListCell()<NSTextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *categoryLabel;
@property (assign) BOOL editing;
@property (copy) NSString* category;
@end

@implementation CategoryListCell
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor {
   self.editing = YES;
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor; {
   if (self.editing) {
        self.editing = NO;
        [self mergeFromSource:self.category toDestination:self.categoryLabel.stringValue];
   }
   return YES;
}

- (void)mergeFromSource:(NSString*)source toDestination:(NSString*) destination {
 // your work here
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to subclass the `NSView` that's in the `NSTableView` cell and make the subclassed view a delegate of the textfield.  Your view will then get text change notifications via the `NSTextField` delegate method:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
```